# Java application throws so many times same Exception

Tags: java, exception, jboss, out-of-memory

We use in our application these technology. Java, JBoss, JMS, EJB .

```
Package com/net/config/server/security/AccessController.java

public void checkGlobalPermissions throws NotAuthorizedException {

throw new NotAuthorizedException();
}

Package com/net/config/server/services/ejb/jboss/ServiceSecurityProxy.java

void checkCreatePermission(){
AccessController ac = AccessController.getInstance();
ac.checkGlobalPermissions();
}

Package com/net/config/server/services/ejb/ServiceBean.java
try {
        securityProxy.checkCreatePermission(type, folderId);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.error(this, "Exception in check readonly permission for     type:"+type, ex);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

When we run our application on jboss server, we are getting infinite exceptions thrown from this piece of code. Here is the exception stack trace.

```
2012-09-20 11:55:17,792 ERROR [com.powerup.configmgr.server.services.ejb.ServiceBean]        (http-0.0.0.0-8881-4)     
Exception in check readonly permission for type:Folder
com.net.config.server.security.NotAuthorizedException: securityException.authenFailed
       at       com.net.config.server.security.AccessController.checkGlobalResourcePermissions(AccessController.java:168)
       at com.net.config.server.services.ejb.jboss.ServiceSecurityProxy.checkCreatePermission(ServiceSecurityProxy.java:219)
    at com.net.config.server.services.ejb.ServiceBean.checkReadOnlyPermission(ServiceBean.java:92)
    at com.net.config.server.services.ejb.ServiceBean.getItemDetails(ServiceBean.java:491)
    at com.net.config.server.services.ejb.ServiceBean.getAllItemDetails(ServiceBean.java:395)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2272.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.invocation.Invocation.performCall(Invocation.java:345)
    at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionContainer.java:214)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityProxyInterceptor.invoke(SecurityProxyInterceptor.java:175)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:185)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.java:130)
    at org.jboss.webservice.server.ServiceEndpointInterceptor.invoke(ServiceEndpointInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.CallValidationInterceptor.invoke(CallValidationInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptor.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptor.java:105)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.runWithTransactions(TxInterceptorCMT.java:335)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.invoke(TxInterceptorCMT.java:166)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:192)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invoke(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:122)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:96)
    at com.powerup.service.jboss.plugins.RetryInterceptor.invoke(RetryInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.internalInvoke(SessionContainer.java:624)
    at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:873)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor319.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
    at org.jboss.invocation.http.servlet.InvokerServlet.processRequest(InvokerServlet.java:147)
    at org.jboss.invocation.http.servlet.InvokerServlet.doPost(InvokerServlet.java:209)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.CustomPrincipalValve.invoke(CustomPrincipalValve.java:39)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:407)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

This exception throws 2000 times in 6 hours. I could not identify what could be the cause for this. But noticed that `ServiceSecurity class` doesnot handle this `NotAuthorized Exception`. It is in prodcution box so could not reproduce the issue in house.
This leads to more number of `JMS` spyobject exceptions and at last getting `Out of memory` error.
 so Can anyone help on this?

Comment: infinite and 2000 times in 6 hours in not the same

Comment: `exception throws 2000 times in 6 hours` -- That is really a finite exception..

Comment: Add some more relevant information about environment which you are working ?

Comment: The AccessController is preventing your application from accessing a folder you haven't granted it access to. If you want the software to access that folder you need to grant it, and if its not supposed to access that folder you should fix your software so it doesn't do it.

Comment: I feel deciding logic thru exception handling is a bad idea, and in this particular case, it can be easily avoided by changing checkGlobalPermissions boolean type and removing the exception all together.

Answer (score 1):

> But noticed that `ServiceSecurity[Proxy]` class doesnot handle this `NotAuthorizedException`

I suspect `NotAuthorizedException` is a `RuntimeException`, therefore `ServiceSecurityProxy` doesn't need to handle or declare it.

To me, it looks like your code is working exactly how I would expect.  Perhaps you are expecting a different `ServiceSecurityProxy` to be injected?

Comment: Thanks for your response. NotAuthorizedException extends java.lang.SecurityException which extends java.lang.RuntimeException.